# check if items in array of unknown size all have the same property value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array of undefined size that holds objects with the same propertynames. What I am looking for, is a clean way to check if all of these items have the same value assigned to a specific property or not.

Example
[{age:10}, {age:10}]

I need a way to return true in this case, since age is the same on all objects. If one object would have any other value than 10 it would have to return false.

My approach was a for loop, saving the first iterations value and check if the next is the same otherwise return. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: Use the `Array.every()` method.

Comment: but can you pass in a param to .every besides the currentValue it takes as the first?

Comment: Why do you need to? The callback function can access outside variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following

```js
const checkPropertyIsEqual = (myArray, propertyName) => {
    const res = myArray.map(arrayItem => arrayItem[propertyName]);
    return (new Set(res).size === 1); 
}


console.log(checkPropertyIsEqual([{age: 10}, {age: 10}], "age"))
console.log(checkPropertyIsEqual([{age: 20}, {age: 10}], "age"))
```

Comment: `checkPrortyIsEqual`. Did you mean `checkPropertyIsEqual`?

Comment: yes @Andy! Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Write a little helper function that accepts the array, and the property to inspect, create an array of values using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and check if they are all same with [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
const arr = [{age:10}, {age:10}];
const arr2 = [{age:1}, {age:10}];
const arr3 = [{name:'Bob'}, {name:'Bob'}];
const arr4 = [{name:'Bob'}, {name:'Steve'}];

// For every object in the array are all the values
// of the property the same value
function sameValue(arr, prop) {
  if (!arr.length) return 'Array is empty';
  return arr
    .map(el => el[prop])
    .every((el, _, arr) => el === arr[0]);
}

console.log(sameValue(arr, 'age'));
console.log(sameValue(arr2, 'age'));
console.log(sameValue(arr3, 'name'));
console.log(sameValue(arr4, 'name'));
console.log(sameValue([], 'name'));
```

Comment: I think the idea is that he doesnt necessarily know what `value` can be.

Comment: Yeah, I misread it. Thanks @callback.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's that much cleaner, but you could try using array methods:

```js
const a = {
  someOtherProp: true
};
const b = {
  age: 10
};
const c = {
  age: 10
};
const d = {
  age: 20
};

let shouldBeTrue = [a, b, c].filter(x => x.hasOwnProperty('age')).map(x => x.age).every((x, _, arr) => x === arr[0]);
let shouldBeFalse = [a, b, c, d].filter(x => x.hasOwnProperty('age')).map(x => x.age).every((x, _, arr) => x === arr[0]);

console.log(shouldBeTrue);
console.log(shouldBeFalse);
```

This should give you the desired result.

Comment: What is the expected output?

It's not returning anything and if I try to assign it to a variable and log the variable, it returns false even the properties are the same

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a script.
Basically the code filters the array for elements which include the required property (this step could be skipped if we know beforehand that each element must include the property) and then uses .every to check for equality.

Answer (score 0):

## use Array.every()

```
const ages = [{ age: 10 }, { age: 10 }, { age: 10 }];

var isSameValue = ages.every((ele) => {
  return ele.age === 10;
});
console.log(isSameValue); //true
```